# Find the line integral using the fundamental theorem of line integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

$$\int_C (1+\cosh(y),x\sinh(y))d\vec{s}$$
Where C is a curve that goes from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$

I am not sure on how to proceed, I can find

$\vec{F}=(1+\cosh(y),x\sinh(y))$

$\vec{f}:\nabla f=\vec{F}$

$\vec f=(x+x\cosh(y), x\cosh(y))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamental theorem of line integrals: if $f = \nabla F$ and $c$ is a contour from $a$ to $b$

$\int_c f \cdot dr = F(b) - F(a)$

The line integral does not depend on the path. It only depends on the endpoints.

$f = \nabla (x+x \cosh y)$

$\int_c f\cdot dr = 1 + \cosh 1$

Comment: Can you explain how you got to $f$?

Comment: Looks like you already have it.  I am going to give technique that I have been reprimanded for showing before, but I think it is easy to follow.  $f = \frac {\partial F}{\partial x}, \frac {\partial F}{\partial y} \implies F = \int 1 + \cosh y \ dx =  \int x\sinh y \ dy = x + x\cosh y + g(y) = x\cosh y + h(x) $  Now find any $g(y), h(x)$ that solve the equation

Comment: @DougM what is wrong with this technique?

Comment: @qbert one of the other regulars on this site, thought that the methods to find $g(y), h(x)$ were prone to error except in the simplest of cases, and was recommending a more algorithmic (rules based) approach that while more explicit is less intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You are in search of a function $f$ with the property that 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1+\cosh y\implies f(x,y)=x+x\cosh y+g(y)
$$
furthermore, you would like 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x\sinh y+g'(y)=x\sinh y\implies g(y)=c
$$
and 
$$
f(x,y)=x+x\cosh y+c
$$
try evaluating the potential $f$ at the end points.

Comment: could you further explain how you got to $f(x,y)$?